# Allowing user to rename the django model field names visible to him

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model like below. I want the user to be able to change the "external" field names (i.e. what is visible to the user) using some form of `Legend` (the internal field names should be the same: `Product.rating1` should not change). The user opens the `Product` form he sees the default name of the fields (e.g. `'Rating 1'` is called `'Rating 1'`). But the user should be able to change this in a different form (e.g. `'Rating 1'` to `'Some random name'`). This new rating name should now be changed for all `Product`s.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    rating1 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    rating2 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    rating3 = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Legend(models.Model):
    rating1_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='Rating 1')
    rating1_abbr = models.CharField(max_length=2, default='R1')
    rating2_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='Rating 2')
    rating2_abbr = models.CharField(max_length=2, default='R2')
    rating3_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='Rating 3')
    rating3_abbr = models.CharField(max_length=2, default='R3')
```

**Desired result:** The `Product`'s database table will contain several products. However, the database table of `Legend` will just contain one entry that is created from the start (automatically) and it will never be deleted, the fields will just be changed. What I want is basically to in one place of my app have a form that creates these `Product`s and another form (somewhere else) that can change the names of these categories.

I don't want the alternative names to be in the `Product` model, since each product will then have a different rating name. I also don't know how to create the initial `Legend` database entry from the start.

What is the best way to do this? Sorry if I'm missing something trivial.

Answer (score 0):

pass `Legend`  objects and `form`  to your html and after

```
{% for value in Legend %}
    {{ value.rating1_name }}: {{ form.rating1 }}
    {{ value.rating2_name }}: {{ form.rating2 }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks! I do know how to do the forms and templates (forgot to say that), but how can I create the Legend from the start. You see, it needs to be created before the user opens the form, since the form (and the rest of the app for that matter) will be populated with the default values.

Comment: You could try Django signals https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/signals/#listening-to-signals maybe that will help.

Answer (score 0):

In your products page you can show the details of the product such as name and values of rating fields. You can also show the current name(legend) of that particular rating field.

```
        {% for product in products %}
            <h2>{{ product.name }}</h2>
            {% for l in legends %}
                <h4>{{ l.rating1_name }} = {{ product.rating1 }}</h4>
                <h4>{{ l.rating2_name }} = {{ product.rating2 }}</h4>
                <h4>{{ l.rating3_name }} = {{ product.rating3 }}</h4>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
```

Then you can have a completely separate legends page so that user can set the values of the legends.

```
    {% for l in legend %}
        <h3>Legend 1 </h3>
        <input type="text" name="rating1" value="{{ l.rating1_name }}">
        <h3>Legend 2 </h3>
        <input type="text" name="rating2" value="{{ l.rating2_name }}">
        <h3>Legend 3 </h3>
        <input type="text" name="rating3" value="{{ l.rating3_name }}">
    {% endfor %}
```

Then you can update the new values of legends by using python logic, you can make a new function to perform this particular task in your views.py or you can create a new file as well and make a method over there to complete the task.

```
def _update_legends(request):
     for l in legends
         l.rating1_name =  l.rating1_name 
         l.rating2_name =  l.rating2_name
          l.rating3_name =  l.rating3_name
```

I hope you would understand it, and solve your problem I tried hard to make you understand.